# C# HttpWebRequest second POST request

Tags: c#, caching, post, httpwebrequest

I'm having problems with a second HttpWebrequest (POST) at the same POST URL.

This is how my program works now, and it does almost everything good except for one thing.

1. It's logging in to the website I want (a game website)
2. It's doing a GET request at the marketplace of this game, to grab the sourcecode with a streamreader and put this into a variable with the type of a string, and using RegEx to find 2 different tokens (reloadToken & RTVT), which are different at every pageload and need to be posted.
3. It's doing a POST request at the POST-URL of this 'marketplace', the result: the bid is accepted and that is what I want.

But, this needs to be done every hour one time. But however, when the next hour appears it's sending a POST request again, but this time it's not accepted.

My first guess would be some caching problem or something like that (maybe it's posting the wrong reloadToken and RTVT?), or some problem with cookies maybe?

I tried deleting all cookies after it bids and let it relog and repost to bid again, but also this did not resolve my problem.

Is there something I forgot to do, I should do extra to let this POST request work at the same URL but with different data (reloadToken & RTVT).

Comment: Your second post request could be failing for any number of reasons. Debug and inspect or log whatever is returned by the second post.

Comment: Yes, but how can this be possible? Since those requests are almost the same, only the RTVT and reloadToken are different. 
Is it possible to be some caching problem or something like that? Maybe it's using the old strings or doing the RegEx at the old string variable which contains the source? Just guessing.